# Pass employeeno as an argument to procedure and modify salary to that employee?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

ORA-06550: line 4,column 3
PLS-00905: object HR.procempno is invalid

-- I have tried this code --

```
create or replace procedure procempno(p_no in number)
IS
  v_salary number(10,2);
begin
  v_salary:=(select salary from emp where employee_id=p_no);
if v_salary>1000 then
  update emp set salary=v_salary*1.75;
else 
  update emp set salary=5000;
end if;
Exception when no_data_found then
  dbms_output.put_line(p_empno||' doesnt exists');
end procempno;
```

-- Below is my recent code --

```
create or replace procedure procempno(p_no in number)
IS
v_salary number(10,2);
begin
  select salary into v_salary from emp where employee_id=p_no;
  if v_salary>1000 then
    update emp set salary=v_salary*1.75 where employee_id=p_no;
  else 
    update emp set salary=5000 where employee_id=p_no;
  end if;
Exception when no_data_found then
  dbms_output.put_line(p_empno||' doesnt exists');
end procempno;
```

-- Executing using PLSQL block --

```
declare 
  v_empno number;
begin
  procempno(&v_empno);
end;
```

Lets consider, empno=100 has salary=25000.
If we give input for empno =100 then it checks the condition whether 25000>1000 if yes then update the salary=salary*1.75. Otherwise update salary =5000

Comment: Use `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see why the procedure is invalid. I'm nit sure why you've left your first attempt in the question as you've already fixed it's biggest problem. And the second appears to just have a typo, `p_empno` instead of `p_no`? (You don't need PL/SQL for this at all, but I guess this is an exercise...)

Comment: You really need to get familiar with the way whatever dev tool you are using reports compilation errors, as you would for any other programming language. You can’t realistically spend your development career noticing that objects are invalid and wondering what the problem could possibly be.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typing error on line

```
dbms_output.put_line(p_empno||' doesnt exists');
```

you should use **p_no**

```
dbms_output.put_line(p_no||' doesnt exists');
```

Don't forget the **COMMIT**, and use a good code standard

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procempno(p_no IN emp.employee_id%TYPE) IS
  v_salary emp.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary
    INTO v_salary
    FROM emp
   WHERE employee_id = p_no;

  IF v_salary > 1000
  THEN
    UPDATE emp
       SET salary = v_salary * 1.75
     WHERE employee_id = p_no;
  ELSE
    UPDATE emp
       SET salary = 5000
     WHERE employee_id = p_no;
  END IF;

  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(p_no || ' doesnt exists');
END procempno;
```

Comment: You could simplify the code by writing this:  UPDATE emp
     SET salary = CASE WHEN v_salary > 1000
                    THEN v_salary * 1.75
                    ELSE 5000
                  END
   WHERE employee_id = p_no;

Comment: It is not usually considered good practice to commit inside a procedure. The caller should manage the transaction control.

Comment: @DonDorian I have done corrections as per your code but Still error occurs

Comment: Have a look on executing plsql block code is there any mistake

Comment: @Bruno you're right about the "commit", but you should keep in mind he is starting and you know the consequences about forgetting a "commit".  When I said "code standard" I meant: indentation, capitalization, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid selecting current salary into a local variable and update it directly. For prettier output, I did declare `RETVAL` which will be used to display a new salary.

Here's an example: first, I'll create a temporary table based on Scott's EMP table (so that it looks like yours):

```
SQL> create table t_emp as
  2    select empno as employee_id,
  3           sal   as salary
  4    from emp;

Table created.
```

The procedure: useful part is lines 5 - 9 which do what you wanted. The rest isn't necessary.
In lines 12-16 I'm checking whether anything was updated (i.e. the employee with `P_NO` exists - note that I don't need exception handler for `NO_DATA_FOUND` in this case).

```
SQL> create or replace procedure procempno (p_no in number)
  2  is
  3    retval t_emp.salary%type;
  4  begin
  5    update t_emp e set
  6      e.salary = case when e.salary > 1000 then e.salary * 1.75
  7                      else 5000
  8                 end
  9      where e.employee_id = p_no
 10      returning e.salary into retval;
 11
 12    if sql%rowcount = 0 then
 13       dbms_output.put_line(p_no || ' does not exist');
 14    else
 15       dbms_output.put_line('Salary updated to ' || retval);
 16    end if;
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin procempno(7369); end;
  2  /
Salary updated to 5000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin procempno(7499); end;
  2  /
Salary updated to 2800

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin procempno(1111); end;
  2  /
1111 does not exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```